# Groupbox disappeared in Visual Studio C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a GroupBox with some buttons, topdowns and labels in it. But in the preview it disappeared.
I still have the code behind but how can I get it back?

Comment: Which UI framework are you using (WinForms, WPF, etc.). Please [edit] the question and post the "code-behind" so that someone could help you figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Again, there isn't enough information for us to help you. Kindly include the code in your `*.Designer.cs` file (only the relevant parts if it's too long) so we can help you figure out what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Open your form in design mode and on the properties (in SharpDevelop, VS might be similar) select your groupbox from the top combo box.
Check if all properties are set correctly (especially Visible, AutoSize and Size)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A8ik.png)